# Trying to generate objects from a class

Tags: python, function, object, assign

Trying to create a list of Object Person, what am I doing wrong? Cannot assign function to call

```
import names
import random
spa1 = []
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
for i in range (100):
  p(i) = Person(names.get_full_name(),randint(1,100))
  datum= p(i).name,p(i).age
  spa1.append(datum)

print(spa1)
```

Comment: What is `p(i)` supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
import names
from random import randint
spa1  = []
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

for i in range (100):
  p = Person(names.get_full_name(),randint(1,100))
  datum= p.name,p.age
  spa1.append(p)

print(spa1)
```

In the original code, there was few problems:

1. `p(i) = Person(names.get_full_name(),randint(1,100))` there is no list `p` and there is no need to store it in a list because 2 lines below the `p` value is append to the `spa1` list.
2. `datum= p(i).name,p(i).age` if `p` is an object there is no need to call it with index.
3. `import random` needed to be changed to `from random import randint` in order to call `randint(1,100)` without `random` before `randint`.